# Logial operator in a variable assignment isn't defaulting to the always true statement

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why this doesn't work when the first value isn't available:

```
var borough = state.city.borough || 'Manhattan';
```

It returns:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: state is not defined

I would expect it to default to `Manhattan` when `state.city.borough` isn't defined.

Edit: I am looking for a solution that will work if the "state" object or any of it's keys are not available.

Comment: You can't dereference an object that is not defined, so you have to check for all potentially undefined parts: `var borough = state && state.city && state.city.borough || 'Manhattan';`

Comment: If `state` is not declared/defined your code won't work at all

Comment: make an answer @HunterMcMillen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test for existence of nested JavaScript object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen that returns the same answer.

Comment: of course, `state` is not declared!!!

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I meant to say same error

Comment: @user3006927 Obviously, the variable `state` has to be declared somewhere. Having a value of undefined is not the same as not existing.

Comment: It seems like they actually want something like this: `var borough; try { borough = state.city.borough; } catch (e) { borough = 'Manhatten'; }; `. Which is absurd

Comment: @HunterMcMillen this is what I'm looking for...Why is it absurd?

Comment: I can't think of many reasons why you would be trying to reference an object called `state` but have not previously declared it somewhere. Maybe if you showed more of your surrounding code we could help more

Answer (score 0):

Once you fixed the reason why `state` is declared nowhere you may run into another issue: once `state` or `state.city` return null or undefined you will still get an error.

Workarounds are:

1. check every single member in the chain:

   ```
   var borough = (state && 
               state.city && 
               state.city.borough) || 'Manhattan';
   ```
2. use something similar to lodash's [_.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#get) or write your own version:

   ```
   var borough = _.get(state, 'city.borough', 'Manhattan');
   ```
3. use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) from ES6

   ```
    var {city: {borough = 'Manhattan'}} = state;
   ```
4. wait until [elvis operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) is aprooved as part of standard and implemented in major borwsers(or you may apply [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to use this [right now](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-null-safe-accessor))

   ```
   var borough = state?.city?.borough || 'Manhattan';
   ```

[UPD] missed that point: you have syntax error because `state` has not been ever defined; not because it's null or something like that

Comment: I think you need a `this` someplace or you have the same undefined `state` problem in 1

Comment: @JonSG I agree that those alternatives will not help in case author does not put  declaration for `var state` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If state is not declared then it is not declared .  However, `this` is defined so assuming that it is reasonable that at some point to expect `state === this.state` then try:

```
var borough = (
    this.state &&
    this.state.city &&
    this.state.city.borough) || 'Manhattan';
```

Answer (score -1):

This appens because in javascript,if you try to access the property of an undefined object the compiler crashes,so you need to check for the existence of each one of the property you are trying to access:

```
var borough;

if (state && state.city && state.city.borough) {
  borough = state.city.borough;
}
else {
  borough = 'Manhattan';
}
```

Comment: did you declare the state object somewhere? I assumed that in my answer but if you didn't declare at all the state object of course it will throw an error

Answer (score -2):

You can't de-reference an object that is no value, so you have to check for all potentially undefined parts:

```
var state = undefined;
var borough = state && state.city && state.city.borough || 'Manhattan';
```